# How to export C functions from DLL

Tags: c, gcc, dll

Trying to access the function "Swap" from mylib.dll.

**Swap.c (mylib.dll)**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
* Swap the content of the variables pointed by a and b
*/
__declspec(dllexport) void Swap(int *a, int *b) 
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;

    printf("Initial values: \n x = %d; y = %d \n\n", x, y);

    Swap(&x, &y);

    printf("Values after calling Swap: \n x = %d; y = %d \n", x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -shared -o mylib.dll Test.c
```

- Load library with LoadLibrary - Success
- GetProcAddress - Returns NULL

[image: Dep Walker]

Comment: Did your test program do anything when executed?

Comment: well, how did you call LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the program works if i compile as an exe but I still cannot access exported functions.

Comment: @user253751 I am using Winbinder functions which ultimatley calls LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress https://github.com/crispy-computing-machine/Winbinder/blob/master/wb/wb_lowlevel.c

Comment: Are you sure Winbinder makes the right LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress calls?

Comment: Yes, I use it with several other dll libraries with no problem.

Comment: Are you using *MinGW* as a build toolchain? Can you share the client code (that uses the wrapper library)? Also did you try creating a small program that loads the function manually (without other software)?

Comment: Yes currently using MinGW.

The windbinder code is currently just a sinlge PHP test script containing
`$dll = 'mylib.dll';`

`$lib = \wb_load_library($dll);`

`$pfn = \wb_get_function_address("Swap", $lib);`
`\var_dump(\wb_call_function($pfn, []));`

I havent tried calls directly to LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress but I will try that.